# Gulp + Browsersync fast with SASS, slow with JS

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, browser-sync

I find it a bit odd that almost the same gulp code is fast to reload with Browsersync (instantaneous) when CSS changes but slow when JS changes.

Can someone point out why my JS reload is taking about 2 seconds?

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
  browserify({
    entries: './src/index.jsx',
    extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.js.jsx'],
    debug: true
  })
  .transform(babelify, { presets: ["es2015", "react"] })
  .bundle().on('error', util.log)
  .pipe( source('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
  .pipe(browsersync.reload({stream:true}));
})

gulp.task('css', function () {
  sass_config = config.sass;
  var css_stream = gulp.src('stylesheets/theme-default.css');

  imports = [
    "font-awesome.min.css",
    "bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css",
    "react-big-calendar.css",
  ]

  for (var i=0; i < imports.length; i++) {
    css_stream = merge(css_stream, gulp.src("stylesheets/" + imports[i]));
  }

  sass_stream = gulp.src(sass_config.src)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass(sass_config.settings))
    .on('error', util.log)
    .pipe(autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 version'] }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write());

  return merge(css_stream, sass_stream)
    .pipe(concat('application.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(sass_config.dest))
    .pipe(browsersync.reload({stream:true}));
});

gulp.task('watch-sass', ['browsersync'], function(callback) {
  watch("./stylesheets/**/*.{sass,scss}", function() { gulp.start('css'); });
});

gulp.task('watch-js', ['browsersync'], function(callback) {
  gulp.start('js');
  watch("./src/**", function() { gulp.start('js'); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps.

> As a browserify project begins to expand, the time to bundle it slowly gets longer and longer. While it might start at 1 second, it's possible to be waiting 30 seconds for your project to build on particularly large projects.

1. https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md
2. https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1004